# How do I get a range of cells to each cell name array in PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to put some comments to cells. But if I put range, than I see error:

```
Cell coordinate string can not be a range of cells.
```

I need a function that can convert my range to array of cells for loop.

For example, if I have (A6:A11) => array(A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11).

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a range of cells when using the need to set each comment individually

But there is a helper function that will allow you to split a range string to an array of individual cell addresses that you can then loop over:

```
foreach(PHPExcel_Cell::extractAllCellReferencesInRange('A6:A11') as $cellAddress) {
    $objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getComment($cellAddress)
        ->getText()
        ->createTextRun('My comment for all cells in the range A6 to A11');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark! This function also works with individual cell, not only for range of cells. No need to add conditions to check range before.